# How to use a bool to prevent loading twice in a class

Tags: c++, stl

I have a class which I want to use a `preLoad` boolean to prevent it being loaded twice in my loop.

I do that like this:

```
Sprite::Sprite(std::string& imagefile)
{
 if(!preload){
    if(!texture.loadFromFile(imagefile)){
        exit(2);
    }

    sprite = sf::Sprite(texture);
    width = sprite.getLocalBounds().width;
    height = sprite.getLocalBounds().height;
    preload = true;
 }
}
```

The problem is that `preload` seems to start off `true` rather than `false`. The variable is set in the class like so:

```
private:
bool preload;
```

But, I need to set it to `false` first but it won't allow me to assign a `false` to it in the header. What can I do to set it to `false` initially?

Comment: Looks like you want a static member.

Comment: There are many potential solutions. Please show the "loop" to which you refer so we can have some context.

Comment: @zdan don't see why seeing the loop changes any thing =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a static bool and set it in the cpp file.

```
private:
    static bool preload;
```

in .cpp file

```
//file declarations
bool Sprite::preload = false;

//class functions below...
```

the static keyword will make all object share this same variable, allowing you to call a function just once for the entire life of a program.

Comment: Does this mean i can set it to false before i call the constructor?

Comment: yes, put the assignment i have in my post just below all of your lib declarations.

Comment: I'm bit confused what you mean by below my declarations ? Do you mean the script which sets up objects related to the class?

Comment: i edited my code, for example place that line of code below #include <iostream> and above your constructor(considering your constructor the the first thing after iostream in the file) in the .cpp file. Think of it like a global declaration in main()

Comment: You mean this: http://pastebin.com/kMPVT5vE ? Because i can't do it outside of the class because its under private its inaccessible =/

Comment: No i get `sprites.cpp(2): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`
`sprites.cpp(2): error C2371: 'preload' : redefinition; different basic types`

Comment: @Dave: Change: `CreateSprite::preload = false;` to `bool CreateSprite::preload = false;`.

Comment: whoops, left that out(knew i was missing something). Thanks jerry